# R error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r, object, closures, subset

I am attempting to merge two data frames, zipdata0 and ziplist. ziplist is a list of all NYC zip codes and zipdata0 is a more comprehensive set of zip codes (one part of a multi-part dataset that I read into a csv from a github url as shown below) as well as a few other columns. I subsetted zipdata0 to include only the columns I wanted, as well as omitted missing values and renamed the "jurisdiction name" column to "ZIP" in ziplist. I then attempted to merge the two datasets to only contain those columns in ziplist, since zipdata0 contains hundreds of thousands of zip codes, and I am only interested in the NYC zip codes as found in ziplist. However, when I run the last line of code below, I get the error "  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable ". From my research, this is because the dataframe(s) or column(s) within them are reactive/functions.

```
library(readr)
urlfile = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/xiaodan-zhou/pm25_and_disparity/main/data/data_part1.csv"
zipdata0 <- read_csv(url(urlfile))
ziplist <- read_csv("zip_code_breakdowns.csv")
myzipvars <- c("year", "ZIP", "zcta", "medhouseholdincome", "pm25")
zipdata0 <- zipdata0[myzipvars]
ziplist$ZIP <- ziplist$`JURISDICTION NAME`
nyczip <- df[zipdata0$ZIP %in% ziplist2$ZIP,]
```

However, when I run

```
str(zipdata0)
str (ziplist)
```

I get

```
> str(zipdata0)
tibble [132,900 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ year              : num [1:132900] 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 ...
 $ ZIP               : num [1:132900] 501 501 501 501 501 501 501 501 501 501 ...
 $ zcta              : num [1:132900] 11742 11742 11742 11742 11742 ...
 $ medhouseholdincome: num [1:132900] 64921 64971 65119 65695 67758 ...
 $ pm25              : num [1:132900] 14.3 13.6 13.1 13 12.2 ...
 - attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int [1:27100] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:27100] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
>
```

```
> str(ziplist)
tibble [236 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ JURISDICTION NAME: num [1:236] 10001 10002 10003 10004 10005 ...
 $ ZIP              : num [1:236] 10001 10002 10003 10004 10005 ...
```

Additionally, the outputs for attr(df, "class") are as follows:

```
> attr(ziplist, "class")
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

```
> attr(zipdata0, "class")
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to merge these two dfs? Thank you!

Comment: `df` is the density function of the F distribution.  You can't subset a function.

Comment: My guess is that you previously defined your data in a variable named `df` and forgot to rehydrate this object in a new R session; this is the cost of using base R function names as object names (e.g., `df` and `data` are two very common names for personal/local data). The error is because in R, a "closure" is really just a function and its enclosing environment. Note that `mean$a` obviously fails (because the `mean` function is not a named-list or data.frame), but `mean <- data.frame(a=1); mean$a` now works without the "closure" error.

Comment: Perhaps instead of `df[...]` you meant `zipdata0[zipdata0$ZIP %in% ziplist2$ZIP,]`?

Comment: @r2evans you just saved my life thank you I don't know how I didn't realize this earlier